# Select with ng-options and array as value

Tags: angularjs, arrays, ng-options

I have the following array:

```
$scope.array = [{value: ['a'], name: 'A'}, {value: ['a', 'b'], name: 'A/B'}, {value: ['a', 'b', 'c'], name: 'ABC' }];
```

And I want to add a select to my html loading the data from the array. The point is that I want to put as a value of the option, the value of the key `value` but it's not selecting the default option properly.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="element as element.name for element in array track by element.value" ng-model="form.element"></select>
```

The object that I use for the `ng-model` looks like this when I initiate the application:

```
$scope.form = {element: ['a'], otherField: 'test'}
```

So it should select the first element of the array as default value but it's not working.

You can find the fiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L9gu8ce/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option box needs to contain the item that you are attempting to select. Since you are putting reference objects into the option box, then your your option box must contain an item with the same reference as the item you wish to have selected by default.

I have updated the JS in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L9gu8ce/6/)

Here is the new JS

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.array = [{value: ['a'], name: 'A'}, {value: ['a', 'b'], name: 'A/B'}, {value: ['a', 'b', 'c'], name: 'ABC' }];

    $scope.form = {element: $scope.array[0]}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use ng-options directive the object will have the prototype of your selected object with (in your case) an attribute `value` and an attributes `name`

In your sample something like :`{value: ['a'], name: 'A'}`

So the first thing to do is to set your ng-model with an object with this shape to be abble to choose a default value :

```
$scope.form = {element: {value: ['a'], name: 'A'}}
```

Then it's your track by syntax in your `ng-options` that will define the default value of your select.

you can't use the attribute `value` in your sample because it's an array and `ng-options` don't know how to compare array. `ng-options` can define default value by : id, number or string.

What i advice you it's to use a property like the name (or create an id if you prefer) like that the ng-options will be abble to determine the default value

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="element as element.name for element in array track by element.name" ng-model="form.element"></select>
```

With this only two change your default selection will run